# Dajax installation

Tags: django, dajaxice

I have serious problem with Dajax installation. However dajaxice work correctly dajax does not respond. 

`INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'dajaxice',
    'dajax',
...)`

`TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = ("...
"django.core.context_processors.request",
...)`

`TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    ...
    'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)`

Head section contains those elements:

`{% load dajaxice_templatetags %}`

`src="/static/js/jquery.js"
src="/static/js/functions.js"
src="/static/js/jquery.dajax.core.js"`

`{% dajaxice_js_import %}`

Apart of it, I have `ajax.py` in one of my apps with sample functions. Should I do sth more? Do you see any mistakes ?

Comment: What is the error? Of this way is more easy

Comment: There is even no error, seems like django does not see Dajax at all ;(

Comment: Some error should have. it's possible that this error is a javascript error

Answer (score 1):

Bit late - but I don't see any obvious mistakes. Perhaps you could first to try to get some information on the problem. Does your settings.py have:

```
DEBUG = True
```

you might want to add some loggers to settings.py - e.g:

```
'dajaxice': {
   'handlers': ['file', 'console'],
   'level': 'WARNING',
   'propagate': True,
   },
'dajaxice.DajaxiceRequest': {
   'handlers': ['file', 'console'],
   'level': 'WARNING',
   'propagate': True,
   },
}
```

you also don't state whether or not your ajax.py has imported the required modules, might be worth checking:

```
from dajax.core import Dajax
from dajaxice.decorators import dajaxice_register
```

and from the docs dajax requires jQuery 1.6.2 (and above from my experience). What version are you using?

finally - make sure you add the registration decorator to your ajax.py functions, or otherwise register them as per the documentation http://docs.dajaxproject.com/dajaxice/create-my-first-dajaxice-function.html#create-your-ajax-function

For example:

```
@dajaxice_register
def myexample(request):
    return simplejson.dumps({'message': 'Hello World'})
```

I'm loving Dajax/Dajaxice, although it's allowing me (or I'm allowing myself) to get into a big of a spaghetti bowl of code looping back and forth between python/django & js.